# How can I retrieve a value from a column and apply it to the next row in SQLite for Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a checkbook application and want to get the value of the account after a transaction is applied. I then want to update the subsequent transactions to reflect the new amounts after each transaction. I am using SQLite on Android. I want to input a transaction into the timeline anywhere and if there are any transactions that appear later, the balance will be updated. This should work just like the transactions look like for online banking.

I have tried using for loops, while loops, etc 
I just can't seem to access the right data.

#### Example

```
Transaction 1.        $33.00.        Balance $33.00
Transaction 2.        $5.00.         Balance $38.00
Transaction 3.        $10.00.        Balance $48.00
```

This is my first full app I am working on and and relatively new to coming in general.

Even a pointer in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I used Cursor to get the balance for the transaction of the date prior. I don't know how to input that balance with the new transaction amount into the next row. I have used while( cursor.moveToNext()) and a for loop.

Comment: What you'll have to do is get the previous balance from db and then add or subtract you transaction amount to the balance and insert a new record.

Comment: How would I automate that to apply to all transactions that follow? That is what I can't figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another perhaps easier way for android which updates all balances (could be changed to update from a particular transaction).

The example uses a table named **transaction_table* with columns

- **timestamp** (YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:DD)
- **item** (description of the transaction)
- **amount** (amount that the transaction if for)
- **balance** (the balance as per order according to the timestamp)

  - values amount an balance are integers (java long) (avoids precision issues)

The crux of the solution are two methods used to get the previous transaction balance (`getPreviousBalance`) and to update all balances (`updateBalances`) based upon the retrieved previous balanace (0 if no prior transaction).

The subclass of SQLieOpenHelper (aka the Databasehelper) is **TransactionHelper.java** and is :-

```
public class TransactionHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "transaction.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_TRANSACTION = "transaction_table";
    public static final String COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String COl_TRANSACTION_ITEM = "item";
    public static final String COL_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String COl_TRANSACTION_BALANCE = "balance";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    public TransactionHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_TRANSACTION + "(" +
                COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
                COl_TRANSACTION_ITEM + " TEXT, " +
                COL_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT + " INTEGER, " +
                COl_TRANSACTION_BALANCE + " INTEGER " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertTransaction(String item, long amount, String timestamp) {
        long rv = -1;
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP,timestamp);
        cv.put(COl_TRANSACTION_ITEM,item);
        cv.put(COL_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,amount);
        rv = mDB.insert(TB_TRANSACTION,null,cv);
        updateBalances(); //<<<<<<<<<< Update the balances
        return rv;
    }

    public void logLedger(String description) {
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TB_TRANSACTION,null,null,null,null, null,COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP + " ASC");
        Log.d("LEDGER", "Displaying Ledger - " + description);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(
                    "LEGDER",
                    "Date = " +
                            csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP)) +
                            " Item = " +
                            csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_TRANSACTION_ITEM)) +
                            " Amount = " +
                            String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT))) +
                            " Balance = " +
                            String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_TRANSACTION_BALANCE)))
            );
        }
        csr.close();
    }

    private void updateBalances() {
        String whereclause = COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[1];
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TB_TRANSACTION,null,null,null,null,null,COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP + " ASC");
        mDB.beginTransaction();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            long balance_to_apply = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)) + getPreviousBalance(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP)));
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(COl_TRANSACTION_BALANCE,String.valueOf(balance_to_apply));
            whereargs[0] = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP));
            mDB.update(TB_TRANSACTION,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
        }
        csr.close();
        mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        mDB.endTransaction();
    }

    private long getPreviousBalance(String datetime) {
        long rv = 0;
        String[] columns = new String[]{COl_TRANSACTION_BALANCE};
        String whereclause = COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP + "<?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{datetime};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TB_TRANSACTION,columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,COL_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP + " DESC","1");
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_TRANSACTION_BALANCE));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Testing as undertaken from an Activity namely **MainActivity.java** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TransactionHelper mTAHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTAHlpr = new TransactionHelper(this);

        mTAHlpr.insertTransaction("T001",10000,"2018-01-01 10:30:00");
        mTAHlpr.insertTransaction("T002",20000,"2018-01-01 11:30:01");
        mTAHlpr.insertTransaction("T003",30000,"2018-01-01 12:30:45");


        mTAHlpr.logLedger("After 3 rows inserted");

        mTAHlpr.insertTransaction("T004",100000,"2017-01-01 09:00:00");
        mTAHlpr.logLedger("Another First row inserted");

        mTAHlpr.insertTransaction("T005",200000,"2018-01-01 10:32:00");
        mTAHlpr.logLedger("Row inserted after 2nd");

    }
}
```

The result (the Ledger) :-

> ```
> 11-16 22:32:41.630 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEDGER: Displaying Ledger - After 3 rows inserted
> 11-16 22:32:41.630 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 10:30:00 Item = T001 Amount = 10000 Balance = 10000
> 11-16 22:32:41.630 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 11:30:01 Item = T002 Amount = 20000 Balance = 30000
> 11-16 22:32:41.630 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 12:30:45 Item = T003 Amount = 30000 Balance = 60000
> 11-16 22:32:41.638 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEDGER: Displaying Ledger - Another First row inserted
> 11-16 22:32:41.638 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2017-01-01 09:00:00 Item = T004 Amount = 100000 Balance = 100000
> 11-16 22:32:41.638 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 10:30:00 Item = T001 Amount = 10000 Balance = 110000
> 11-16 22:32:41.638 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 11:30:01 Item = T002 Amount = 20000 Balance = 130000
> 11-16 22:32:41.638 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 12:30:45 Item = T003 Amount = 30000 Balance = 160000
> 11-16 22:32:41.646 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEDGER: Displaying Ledger - Row inserted after 2nd
> 11-16 22:32:41.646 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2017-01-01 09:00:00 Item = T004 Amount = 100000 Balance = 100000
> 11-16 22:32:41.646 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 10:30:00 Item = T001 Amount = 10000 Balance = 110000
> 11-16 22:32:41.646 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 10:32:00 Item = T005 Amount = 200000 Balance = 310000
> 11-16 22:32:41.646 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 11:30:01 Item = T002 Amount = 20000 Balance = 330000
> 11-16 22:32:41.646 1387-1387/so53291104.so53291104 D/LEGDER: Date = 2018-01-01 12:30:45 Item = T003 Amount = 30000 Balance = 360000
> ```

Comment: Ok. This works great but I don't know how I can implement the timestamp. Transaction dates are user input. So right now the hurdle I am facing are same day transactions. I guess this is more of implementation than code

Comment: I got it to work. I appended the transaction ID to the date. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

To automatically do something when inserting/updating/deleting (or even selecting) you can use a TRIGGER which will automatically run.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) (I'd suggest a good read of this)

The following may suffice or be the basis. It copes with your test data (as will be shown) :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS adjust_balance_after_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON transaction_table -- After an insert
        BEGIN
          -- Update the transaction table for this row (and any that are > (likely none))
            UPDATE transaction_table
                -- set the balance to be the new amount + the highest balance of the previous transaction
                SET balance = new.amount + (
                    SELECT
                        CASE 
                            WHEN
                                -- if no previous transaction then balance is 0 (may need to cater for a starting balance, although that could be the first transaction)
                                (SELECT max(balance) FROM transaction_table WHERE id = (new.id - 1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) IS NULL THEN 0
                            ELSE
                                -- if there is a previous transaction then the balance is this amount + the balance (max(balance) could be just balance)
                                (SELECT max(balance) FROM transaction_table WHERE id = (new.id - 1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
                            END
                    )
            WHERE id >= new.id ;
        END;
```

The following is the SQL used to test the above :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transaction_table;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS adjust_balanace_after_insert;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transaction_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, item TEXT, amount INTEGER, balance INTEGER);


-- The trigger
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS adjust_balanace_after_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON transaction_table -- After an insert
        BEGIN
          -- Update the transaction table for this row (and any that are > (likely none))
            UPDATE transaction_table
                -- set the blanace to be the new amount + the highest balance of the previous transaction
                SET balance = new.amount + (
                    SELECT
                        CASE 
                            WHEN
                                -- if no previous transaction then balance is 0 (may need to cater for a starting balance, although that could be the first transaction)
                                (SELECT max(balance) FROM transaction_table WHERE id = (new.id - 1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) IS NULL THEN 0
                            ELSE
                                -- if there is a previous transaction then the blanace is this amount + the blanace (max(balance) could be just balance)
                                (SELECT max(balance) FROM transaction_table WHERE id = (new.id - 1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
                            END
                    )
            WHERE id >= new.id ;
        END;

-- Test it
INSERT INTO transaction_table (item,amount) VALUES ('tv001',3300),('tv002',500),('tv003',1000);
SELECT * FROM transaction_table;
```

It results in :-

[image]

- Note INTEGERs (long) have been used which some recommend as REAL (double/floats can lead to issues with precision)
- For android you would create the trigger the same way you would create a table, albeit a little more complex.
- **NOTE** it doesn't handle transactions being **deleted** or **updated**.
- **NOTE** it assumes sequential numbering BUT the **ORDER BY** and **LIMIT** in conjunction with **max(balance)** would only need a more suitable **WHERE** clause (`WHERE id < (new.id)`) to be used.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but still have issues/questions. I have ORDER BY transaction date, as transactions can be input out of order and with days in between transactions. I am using String yyyyMMdd (20181107)  for my date values. I am getting only the first balance as a result for each transaction. Am I to use date in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @PaoloSantaniello yes then must be by date instead of id throughout.However you could only reliably have 1 transaction per date.

Comment: I see. I am getting one total balance for every group of transactions per date...

Comment: Would this work if I were to create a VIEW and use the rowid for the WEHRE? I apologize if this may be a dumb question.

Comment: @PaoloSantaniello gave up on this (problem that you can't use ORDER and LIMIT  as per *The LIMIT and ORDER BY clauses for UPDATE are unsupported within triggers, regardless of the compilation options used to build SQLite.*) So this answer doesn't work for inserted anywhere. Have added an answer as a program solution for Android.